# How to convert a real number to integer while maintaining the sign in VHDL

Tags: integer, vhdl

I have a variable in VHDL code which is real and can be both positive or negative. I am using following to convert it to integer:

```
I_data_integer := integer(I_data_real);
```

Problem is that if **I_data_real** is negative e.g. `-523467.0` the value of **I_data_integer** is positive only i.e. `523467`. My requirement is to pass the sign of the real value to integer.

I am using Questasim 10.4c. Please help!!!

Comment: The function `sign(..)` returns the sign of a real value. But I thought - as you - that an integer conversion just returns the integer part of a real incl. sign, because integers incl. neg. numbers, while using `natural(..)` as conversion should result in a (runtime) error  ...

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example such that we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could there be an error somewhere else in your code? Here's the test that I just tried:

```
entity RealTest is
end RealTest;

architecture Behavioral of RealTest is

  signal value_real : real := -523467.0;
  signal value_integer : integer;

begin

  process
  begin
    report "real: " & real'image(value_real);
    value_integer <= integer(value_real);
    wait for 0 ns;
    report "integer: " & integer'image(value_integer);
    wait;
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

In ModelSim:

> vcom RealTest.vhd
>   vsim RealTest
>   run 1 ns

Output:

> ** Note: real: -5.234670e+005
>   Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /realtest
>   ** Note: integer: -523467
>   Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /realtest

This seems to work properly. I'm running ModelSim 10.4c.

Comment: Can you add your vcom/vsim version number just for comparison with the OPs version.